# TCPDF Add Image Rendered By Php

Tags: php, image, tcpdf

i am having issues to add image on pdf file using tcpdf. my image is rendered by php script.

below is the script call mode: (worked well when directly check on browser):

```
./Image.php?t=1049&e=100003&i=25040907060040
```

but when i try to add using tcpdf using below code:

```
$pdf->Image('./Image.php?t=1049&e=100003&i=25040907060040', '', '',  20, 20, 'jpg', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

it fails with following errors:

Error 1:

```
Warning: getimagesize(./Image.php?t=1049&e=100003&i=25040907060040): failed to open stream: No error in .\Classes\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_images.php on line 171
```

Error 2:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(./Image.php?t=1049&e=100003&i=25040907060040): failed to open stream: No error in .\Classes\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 7033
```

so, how can i add image using above php script (Image.php)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because your code looks for a data stream for image data.

The best solution is to include `Image.php` which will have a function to output image data.

Suppose the `Image.php` have class `ImageRenderer` with a public function called `render_image()`;

The you can have the image rendered to the PDF like this..

```
require_once('Image.php');

$dynimage = ImageRenderer::render_image(1049,100003,25040907060040); // Parameters t=1049&e=100003&i=25040907060040
// $dynimage will have some data like 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
$imgdata = base64_decode($dynimage); // decode stream
// The '@' character is used to indicate that follows an image data stream and not an image file name
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, yes i already did that.. (read as image data) but i was willing to use that script. because i also have to use  same php scrpt to show as html report in img element like <img src='./Image.php?t=1049&e=100003&i=25040907060040' /> so, i think there may be way to use tcpdf in the same manner but what i don't know :) however, thanks again for your help..